# Displaying long equations in multiple lines

Tags: equations, align, split, multline

I compiled this Tex codes in https://www.latex4technics.com/. The codes are correctly compiled in MathJax but failed in Latex. I am confused about this. How can I have my long equation displayed in multiple lines in Latex? Can I left-align it?

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \delta_{CNN}=  f_n\left(w_n\ast f_{n-1}\left(\cdots
    \left(w_2\ast f_1\left(w_1\ast\left[
    \begin{matrix}\mu_1\\\mu_2\\\end{matrix}\right]\right. \nonumber \\
    \left.+b_1\right)+b_2\right)\cdots\right)+b_n\right),
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You're missing the correct number of  `\left.` and of `\right.` Anyway, it it is better to specify by hand the size of the delimiters, with \bigl(,\Bigl(, \biggl, \Biggl, and similarly for the right delimiters. Also, are you sure it has to be split?

Comment: mathjax isn't LaTeX. Period.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need two lines. Here is a simplified code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
 \delta_{CNN}= f_n\left(w_n\ast f_{n-1}\left(\cdots\left(w_2\ast f_1\left(w_1\ast\begin{bmatrix}\mu_1\\ \mu_2\end{bmatrix}%
+b_1\right)+b_2\right)\cdots\right)+b_n\right),
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you must split the equation across two rows, you should replace all `\left` auto-sizing directives in row 1 with `\Bigl` and all `\right` directives in row 2 with `\Bigr`. Then, get rid of the remaining `\left.` and `\right.` directives.

Incidentally, even if you provided correct number of `\right.` directives in row 1 and the correct number of `\left.` directives in row 2, the auto-sizing approach wouldn't generate the desired result because there's no "tall" object in the second row.

Finally, do insert `&` markers to create alignment points.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'split' and 'bmatrix' environments
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \delta_{\mathrm{CNN}}
    &=  f_n\Bigl(w_n\ast f_{n-1}\Bigl(\cdots\Bigl(w_2\ast f_1\Bigl(w_1\ast
        \begin{bmatrix} \mu_1 \\ \mu_2 \end{bmatrix}    \\[1ex]
    &\quad +b_1\Bigr)+b_2\Bigr)\cdots\Bigr)+b_n\Bigr)\,.
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end {document}
```